# Adding " \\ \hline " after every component of a vector

Tags: r, latex

Consider the following:

```
v <- letters[1:4]
v
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

I would like the following output using `v`:

```
"a \\ \hline b \\ \hline c \\ \hline d \\ \hline"
```

or the version with quotation marks removed. The closest I've gotten to this is

```
paste0(v, collapse = " \\ \\hline ")
[1] "a \\ \\hline b \\ \\hline c \\ \\hline d"
```

and then I `CTRL + F` for Find and Replace in RStudio using `\\hline` -> `\hline`, which is simple enough, but I would like to see if there's a way to just create this string without that extra step.

This problem comes up when I want to create a `tabular` environment using a character vector in an `.Rnw` file using `LaTeX` code.

Comment: If you check the `cat` by printing, it would be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for printing, we can use `cat`

```
cat(v, sep = " \\\\ \\hline ")
```